# Jhipster registry "Status: (Unauthorized)" page after keycloak login

Tags: docker, keycloak, jhipster-registry

Jhipster registry:v3.3.0 
Keycloak: 4.5.0.Final (https enabled)

There is a jhipster registry setup using docker-compose as shown in picture. Registry talks to Keycloak for authentication.

[image: jhipster registry docker setup]

[image: jhipster-registry.yml]
We have two keycloak instances.

When configured with one keycloak instance it successfully logins and opens the registry page.

[image: successful login]

When configured with other keycloak instance it show the following page:
[image: login not successful]

After entering keycloak credentials, the url in the browser is http://localhost:8761/login?state=Swy20H&session_state=c6853b18-42f3-4ad9-9ad0-14615aa576bd&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..xtptsARyYJPbqrhZD4ZF7A.yKur_w3c5H-ybHcpXeBSca1W7N3XxRzQXaUs383Kqh57wzaWt3FhBglGf-w154GRTM93F5oa2grE8HzVyrRpDadQs5FCjpNDZuD86KZy5JVI4RnlYOFvsTMcO-fFi_bWl2ByvNy7QARglrwGQOTeYndvrYluuC57OJGKm8819gIb9a5wvZ9oeiJLuDPwkcefs2J-xnUvEde3yAyVKGxe_oGdA8jJbbwRDQQvCI2e3FLyiKJ1F2P2iHFT5g_QaQxv.7k__JisYiWQrQpjgxJ8m5Q

Same keycloak client was imported in Keycloak realm for instances. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Check Jhipster registry logs. You may see more details about the issue there. You may have a connectivity issue, http vs https issue, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar issue.

In my case I was getting it because of two reasons.

1. The keycloak was SSL enabled and the keystore file used in this
   process did not include Root certificate. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945192) SOS.
2. Our network firewall was blocking the requests to Auth Server. In your case it could be Jhipster registry's backend

Answer (score 0):

you must change configuration in docker file inside your server if you use docker and when enable SSL you must mapping new URI in each docker file

i have the same problem and this is solution for that

```
- SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=http://127.0.0.1/auth/realms/jhipster
```

but after enable ssl your service cannot show above url you must be change it to

```
- SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=https://your-domain.eg/auth/realms/jhipster
```

after that you can authentication without any problem