# Oauth2 login fails for Spring boot application using Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I have a simple Spring boot application (generated using jhipster 5.7.2). No service discovery. Just a simple monolith. It is using Keycloak for auth.

Here is the configuration I selected for my application:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "5.7.2",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "test",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using Keycloak 4.5

I have followed [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_installation/topics/network/https.html) documention to enable HTTPS on my Auth Server. 
Now, my auth server is externally accessible.

My application is running in localhost. When I try to perform login, the login fails with a message : Unauthorized

[image]

Application logs say the following: (BadCredentialsException)

```
2018-12-24 19:31:27.579 DEBUG 43877 --- [ XNIO-2 task-13] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Enter: com.mycompany.myapp.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-12-24T14:01:27.579Z, principal=UNKNOWN, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Could not obtain access token}]]
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
```

No logs on the Keycloak end. If I remove HTTPS related configuration on my auth server, login works. Not sure what exactly is the issue.

Comment: Have you modified the urls under security.oauth2.client in application*.yml to use https .

Comment: yes I have modified them to use https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason for this issue.

In my case, the problem lies in the keystore(JKS) creation process. 
We had only cert.crt and privkey.crt given to us. 
Root certificate was not included while creating the keystore. The [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.4/server_installation/#enabling-ssl-https-for-the-keycloak-server) clearly tell to include root certificate.

Root certificate can be downloaded from the certificate provider. [This](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/installing-trusted-certificates-into-a-java-keystore) link was helpful in including the root certificate.

When playing around with certificates given by [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) all we need to do is use the privkey.pem and fullchain.pem. Here we don't need to worry about including the root certificate as the fullchain.pem already contains it.

```
# convert certificate chain + private key to the PKCS#12 file format
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.pkcs12 -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem

# convert PKCS#12 file into Java keystore format
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks
```